# How to retrieve the change comment for a moment using the REST API?

Tags: rest, versionone

I'm trying to retrieve the last change comment for a member's profile. I see how I can get the last 'moment' for a profile:

`/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Member/[MemberID]?sel=MyLastChangeMoment`

Using that moment ID I can get the last moment

`/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Member/[MemberID]/[MomentID]`

However, that moment data does not include the change comment. How can I retrieve the change comment associated with that moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the last change comment for a Member asset using the **ChangeComment** attribute.

Here's an example query to get the last ChangeComment that was specified for member 20:

```
http://localhost/versionone/rest-1.v1/Data/Member/20?sel=Name,ChangeComment
```